# Clear nested option html form field

Tags: forms, select, html-select, option-type

Do someone know how to clear option nested field in form with f.e. jQuery or simple js?

My form is quite simple (in table):

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">
     <p class="form"><label>Status</label>
    <select  class="wpcf7-form-control" name="StatusId" id="StatusId" required>
      <option value="1" rel="rel1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2" rel="rel1">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3" rel="rel2">Option 3</option>
    </select>
     </p> 
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr rel="rel1">
    <td colspan="2">
      <p class="form">
       <label>Some label 1</label>
        <select class="wpcf7-form-control" name="DepartmentId" id="DepartmentId" data-bvalidator="required" data-bvalidator-msg="required">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Option A</option>
          <option value="2">Option B</option>
          <option value="3">Option C</option>
         </select>
        </p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr rel="rel2">
       <td>
         <p class="form">
           <label>Other status</label>
             <input class="wpcf7-form-control" type="text" name="otherStatus" id="otherStatus" />
         </p>
       </td>
       <td>
         <p class="form">
           <label>Some label 2</label>
           <input class="wpcf7-form-control" type="text" name="otherDepartment" id="otherDepartment" size="41" maxlength="256" />
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the question is, how do this, when we are changing option with main select, the nested options should be cleared. But now they aren't.

Thanks in advance for your answer, I searched many solutions and failed to apply to my form.

Comment: This form using Usable forms 2.0 -> https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/usableforms.html

Comment: Are you saying that when someone changes the choice that's selected in the <select id="statusId" element, you want certain other elements to change?
For that, I would say your best choice would be to use some Javascript.

Comment: I have done this with jQuery script

Comment: Ah excellent. Glad you figured it out.